# Castle DynamicProxy do not call target but do call other interceptors

Tags: castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

I am using Castle's DynamicProxy to intercept method calls. Before executing the target with

```
invocation.Proceed();
```

I check if the result is already in the cache. If so I do not want to call invocation.Proceed . However I do want to execute other interceptors for instance if there is a timing interceptor registered but because I am not calling invocation.Proceed if I found the results in the cache it never get's called. Is there a way around this? Or would I just have to add the timing interceptor to the caching interceptor as well?

Answer (score 1):

Put caching interceptor last in the pipeline.